# How to export multiple tables of DataSet to multiple CSV sheets?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv, dataset

I have a method which exports a DataGridView to CSV. But I have a scenario where I have a DataSet with like 2-3  tables init. I want to Export This to one single CSV file with each Table of DataSet in a seperate CSV sheet.

Here is my method which converts a DataGridView to CSV file (note I will also accept C# code if it can be converted to Vb using online tools):

```
 Private Sub subExportDGVToCSV(ByVal strExportFileName As String, ByVal DataGridView As DataGridView, Optional ByVal blnWriteColumnHeaderNames As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal strDelimiterType As String = ",")

        Dim sr As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(strExportFileName)
        Dim strDelimiter As String = strDelimiterType
        Dim intColumnCount As Integer = DataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim strRowData As String = ""

        If blnWriteColumnHeaderNames Then
            For intX As Integer = 0 To intColumnCount
                strRowData += Replace(DataGridView.Columns(intX).Name, strDelimiter, "") & IIf(intX < intColumnCount, strDelimiter, "")
            Next intX
            sr.WriteLine(strRowData)
        End If

        For intX As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            strRowData = ""
            For intRowData As Integer = 0 To intColumnCount
                strRowData += Replace(DataGridView.Rows(intX).Cells(intRowData).Value, strDelimiter, "") & IIf(intRowData < intColumnCount, strDelimiter, "") '''''''''highlights this row
            Next intRowData
            sr.WriteLine(strRowData)
        Next intX
        sr.Close()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the sheets like xml mapping and parse them when you want to use

CSV:

```
<book>
    <sheet>
    //Sheet 1
    .....
    </sheet>

    <sheet>
    //Sheet 2
    .....
    </sheet>
</book>
```